# I need to print element of a struct that is itself in a map in c++

Tags: c++

I have in c++ an include like that:

```
struct my_struct
{
  time_t time;
  double a, b, c, d;
}
typedef std::map<std::string, std::vector<my_struct> Data;
```

In my code (for debugging issue) I want to print some of the values in Data for specific key. I don't remember the syntax and keep having errors.

Here the kind of syntax I tried without success:

```
for (const auto& [key, value] : inputData) 
{
     if (key=="mytest")
     {
        std::cout << '[' << key << "] = " << value.a << endl;
    }
}
```

I also tried:

```
  for(const auto& elem : inputData)
  {
      if (elem.first=="mytest")
      {
              cout<<elem.second.a>>endl;
      }
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: `value` is a `std::vector<my_struct>`, not a `my_struct` element of the vector. Which element's `.a` do you intend to print?

Comment: This seems a good case for rubber duck programming. Try to explain every step you are trying to take to some inanimate object. Just for now, dont use `auto`. Maybe not even range based loops. So you can explicitly see what types are available at what time in the code. Just small (smaller than you did up to now) to better understand where something is not like you expected it to be.

Comment: Side note: initialize the `double`s in the struct. You don't want to risk uninitialized floating point values, which could be signaling NANs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the following line properly:

```
typedef std::map<std::string, std::vector<my_struct> Data;
```

As you can see the second element of the `std::map` is a list of `my_struct`. Now here:

```
for (const auto& [key, value] : inputData)
{
    if (key == "mytest")
    {
        std::cout << '[' << key << "] = " << value.a << std::endl;
    }
}
```

..`value.a` makes no sense because `std::vector<my_struct>::a` is not a thing.

So replace `value.a` with:

```
value[0].a; // Replace 0 with the index of element you want to access
```

Or print every element in `value`:

```
for (const auto& [key, value] : inputData)
{
    if (key == "mytest")
    {
        std::cout << '[' << key << "] = ";
        for (auto& i : value)
        {
            std::cout << i.a << " : ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

You can use any one of the 2 options as per your choice.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the type of the element of the map:

> ```
> typedef std::map<std::string, std::vector<my_struct> Data;
>                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ```

The map contains vectors.

> ```
> for (const auto& [key, value] : inputData)
> ```

Here, `value` is a value of an element in the map. It is a vector.

> ```
> value.a
> ```

Vector doesn't have a member named `a`. You should be getting error messages that explain this.

There are many ways of accessing elements within vectors. Here is an example:

```
std::cout << value.at(0).a;
```